# Trying to get property of non-object laravel 5.1 on DB::first()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-query-builder

I'm using Laravel 5.1 on a project, and I'm getting "Trying to get property of non-object" error on this code:

```
$eval = DB::table('control_eval_risk_temp')
                   ->where('control_id','=',$control->id)
                   ->where('created_at','=',$max_date)
                   ->select('result')
                   ->first();
if ($eval->result  == 1)
{
     $cont += 1;
}
```

I have this error specifically on the `if` statement, but if I try this:

```
echo getType($eval);
```

That returns `object`, and if I try:

```
echo $eval->result;
```

This returns `1` (so it have a value), and after return the message **Trying to get property of non-`object`**.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Are you sure you've got the right line? Could it be that `$control` is not an object?

Comment: If there are no results, getType($eval) should be "NULL". My suspect is $control as well

Comment: Thank's for your answer, I solve that now it was because this code is on a foreach loop, so in one instance the $eval variable has NULL value which leaded to the mistake.

It was solved adding this to the code:

"if (isset($eval) && $eval != NULL) ... " 

Thank's again for your time!

Comment: Either way, you should definitely check if `$eval` is set before checking its property, like this: `if ($eval && $eval->result  == 1)`

Comment: Totally agree! I passed that and also passed the loop in which the sentence was... Thank's!

Comment: use $eval[0]->result

Comment: try to define $cont =0 and then use condition if ($eval->result  == 1){$cont += 1;}